# How can i horizontally scroll the ion-tab?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, ionic-framework

I want ion-tabs to be horizontally scrollable is it possible for below code

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-default">
     <ion-tab title="About">
          <ion-nav-view name="About-tab"></ion-nav-view>
     </ion-tab>
     <ion-tab title="Global">
           <ion-nav-view name="global-tab"></ion-nav-view>
     </ion-tab>
     <ion-tab title="Friends">
           <ion-nav-view name="Friend-tab"></ion-nav-view>
     </ion-tab>
     <ion-tab title="Family">
           <ion-nav-view name="family-tab"></ion-nav-view>
     </ion-tab>
     <ion-tab title="Business">
            <ion-nav-view name="Business-tab"></ion-nav-view>
     </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Have you tried Ionic Tabbed Slidebox https://github.com/saravmajestic/ionic/tree/master/tabbedSlideBox?